# Why are individual investors called "retail" investors?

Tags: etymology

As far as I understand it, "retail" refer to big stores that sell to individual consumers and retail investors refers to individuals. Wouldn't it make more sense for a "retail investor" to refer to the big companies that engage in mass trading?

Comment: Don't confuse the size of the seller for whether the sale is retail or wholesale. Even if I buy 25 shirts from a clothing shop to wear (or give out to friends or to resell), that is a large retail purchase, not wholesale.

Comment: [Retail](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retail) does not only refer to *large* stores - it refers to selling in small quantities, and small shops or market stalls etc are still retail. I don't know why you think retail is only big stores, but you're mistaken.

Comment: @StuartF, although retail purchases usually involve small quantities, what is crucial to the wholesale-retail distinction is not the quantity as such, but whether the merchandise is intended for resale or not. The purchase of 25 shirts in Mr. Baskin's example is a retail purchase if the purchaser intends to wear them, while a purchase of only 10 shirts may be a wholesale transaction if they are intended for resale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retail in the sense of buyer and seller of generally small quantities of stocks or bonds, usually on a non-professional basis. Contrast with large (wholesale) investors, who are professionals who buy and sell larger quantities (pension/mutual funds etc.)

***[Retail investor](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/retail-investor)***
noun [ C ]   FINANCE, STOCK MARKET
UK  US

> a member of the public who makes investments, not a large organization or business that makes investments:

> - The Bank is wooing retail investors; it has just published a booklet on the virtues of gilts.

(Cambridge Dictionary)